# How can I make my coloured noise sound better?

Tags: noise

I created some coloured noise using Python, and have outputted it as a .wav file.

It works, it's definitely the correct sound, however when compared to other coloured noise sounds available on the internet, like[this (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg0FSu8Gsgg), it sounds very flat and mono.

How can I add 'width' to the sound?

Comment: A lot of ways to add width, when using a random generator you can simply generate for both L + R channels. Otherwise just use any kind of modulation, chorus, phaser, or flanger to taste. You can also use phase cancelation and stereo widening techniques, do a google on how to turn a mono sound to stereo :) as a side note, it'd be good if you could avoid implementations that have delay FX.